# match name and surname from two data frames, extract middle name from one data frame and append it to other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two almost identical data frames A and B. In reality its a two data frames with 1000+ names each.
I want to match name and surname from both data frames and then   extract the middle name from data frame B to data frame A.

```
    data frame A
name         surname
John         Doe
Tom          Sawyer
Huckleberry  Finn
```

```
 data frame    B
name    middle_name  surname
John    `O               Doe
Tom     Philip           Sawyer
Lilly   Tomas            Finn
```

The result i seek:

```
name    middle name    surname
John    `O             Doe
Tom     Philip         Sawyer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with parameter `how='inner'` and `on=['name','surname']`. To get the correct order use `df.reindex` over axis 1.

```
df = df.merge(df1,how='inner',on=['name','surname'])
df.reindex(['name', 'middle_name', 'surname'])

   name middle_name surname
0  John          `O     Doe
1   Tom      Philip  Sawyer
```